# Swiftmailer and adding a variable to setto

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I'm pretty new to writing any sort of code, so please forgive me. I've been attempting to use Swiftmailer to email a copy of a form, with the recipient being a variable depending on what's been entered in a certain field. This is what I have so far:

```
<?php
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();

$choice = $_POST['choice'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

if ($choice == "ghi") {
    $to =  "ghi@ghi.com";
}
elseif ($choice == "def") {
    $to = "def@def.com";
}
elseif ($choice == "abc") {
    $to =  "abc@abc.com";
}

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
$message->setTo($to);
$message->setSubject("subject x");
$message->setBody("$message");
$message->setFrom("noreply@noreply.com");

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$mailer->send($message);
```

But it won't send out the email to any recipients. I have used this method with the standard PHP mailto and it worked fine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem ;) Hard to spot, but the problem simply is that the $message variable and the $message swiftmailer object overwrite each other.. Simply rename $message to something else!